# db_schema can't set foreign key - Table [prefix]_sales_order do not have column with name "name"

Tags: sql, table, foreign-key, foreign-key-constraint

I must add column1 to `sales_order_grid` and create foreign key to
`table sales_grid.column1`
When i try use `bin/magento setup:upgrade` i get next message

> **Table [myPrefix]_sales_order do not have column with name "name1"**

### **In fact, the column exists and I do not confuse names and uppercases**

**module.xml**

```
<module name="Vendor_ModuleName">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        <module name="Magento_Ui"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

**db_schema.xml**

```
<table name="sales_order_grid">
    <column xsi:type="boolean" name="name"/>
    <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="SALES_ORDER_GRID_NAME_SALES_ORDER_NAME" table="sales_order_grid" column="name" referenceTable="sales_order" referenceColumn="nameRef" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
</table>
```

**di.xml**

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">sales_order.label_Name</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

### other info:

docker images:

1. *mariaDB - mariadb:10.4*
2. *nginx - markoshust/magento-nginx:1.18-7*
3. *php-fpm - markoshust/magento-php:7.3-fpm-12*

Answer (score 0):

You have to add InstallData.php to the Setup directory in your module.
Get the order grid table and add your column to the table.

Comment: can i do it with helps db_schema or something yet